# Getting the indices in the initial order

Tags: r

```
> which(LETTERS %in% c("R","A"))
[1]  1 18
```

How can I get the answer `18 1` , i.e. the indices in the order that appear in the initial vector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
match(c("R","A"),LETTERS)

[1] 18  1
```